# Why unsetting data in model does not affect controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

in the **beforeSave()** callback I unset a field doing:

`unset($this->data['Company']['myField']);`

Then, in my Company controller if I do:

`debug($this->request->data)` after the **save()**

I still see the field i unset in the model.

It seems that the change only affect the model scope and not the controller.

how can i update my `$this->request->data` as the data in model?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic OOP. If you do not pass objects along (but data arrays), you cannot - by itself - expect pass by reference.
Therefore modification to the data in your model cannot also alter the data in your request object. After you passed them they are independent.

If you need - for some reason - to update your request object, you need to pull the data again:

```
if ($this->Model->save($this->request->data)) {
    // redirect on success?
}
$this->request->data = $this->Model->data;
```